# downloading and concatenating parts of videos from youtube

Tags: ffmpeg, youtube, youtube-dl, video-editing

I'm trying to create a video quiz, that will contain small parts of other videos, concatenated together (with the purpose, that people will identify from where these short snips are taken from).

For this purpose I created a file that contain the URL of the video, the starting time of the "snip", and its length. for example:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5-j6LLkpQYY   00:00   01:00
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b-DqO_D1g1g   14:44   01:20
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DPAgWKseVhg   12:53   01:00
```

Meaning that the first part should take the video from the first URL from its beginning and last for a minute, the second part should be taken from the second URL starting from 14:44 (minutes:seconds) and last one minute and 20 seconds and so forth.

Then all these parts should be concatenated to a single video.

I'm trying to write a script (I use ubuntu and fluent in several scripting languages) that does that, and I tried to use youtube-dl command line package and ffmpeg, but I couldn't find the right options to achieve what I need.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Hey dude, did you find anything related to this??

Answer (score 1):

Considering the list of videos is in `foo.txt`, and the output video to be `foo.mp4`, this **bash** script should do the job:

```
eval $(cat foo.txt | while read u s d; do echo "cat <(youtube-dl -q -o - $u | ffmpeg -v error -hide_banner -i - -ss 00:$s -t 00:$d -c copy -f mpegts -);"; done | tee /dev/tty) | ffmpeg -i - -c copy foo.mp4
```

This is using a little trick with [process substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst) and `eval` to avoid intermediate files, container `mpegts` to enable simple [concat protocol](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate#protocol), and `tee /dev/tty` just for debugging.

I have tested with `youtube-dl 2018.09.26-1` and `ffmpeg 1:4.0.2-3`.